# como puedo hacer una petición ajax para un archivo svg?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, svg

Trabajo con **myeclipse**, y al momento de llamar a un **mapa.svg**  usando **ajax**, no me aparece.

```
 $.ajax({ 
    url: "resouces/mapa/mapa.svg",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
      var rjs = Raphael('lienzo', 1000, 400);
      $("#div1").html(xml);

      $(xml).find('svg > g > g > path').each(function(){
        var path = $(this).attr('d');
        var pid = $(this).attr('id');
        var munic = rjs.path(path);
        munic.attr(default_attributes);
        munic.hover(function() {
          this.animate({ fill: '#00bbff' });
          $munictxt.html("Municipio: "+pid);
        }, function() {
          this.animate({ fill: default_attributes.fill });
          $munictxt.html("Selecciona un terminal");
        }). click(function() {
          alert("Terminal. ID = "+pid);
        });
          });
      $('#loadingicon').hide();
    }
   });
```

No sé si es por la **url**.

Comment: Sé que es dar palos de ciego, pero no pones que lo hayas hecho, así que ahí van un par de cosas obvias: - en el código pone "resouce" en lugar de "resource", ¿estás seguro de que esa es la dirección correcta?
- para saber si te está dando un 404 la ruta, abre la consola de Chrome/Firefox de desarrollo web, abre la pestaña de Red, y entonces dispara el evento que carga ese mapa. Deberías ser capaz de ver tanto las cabeceras como la ruta completa y la respuesta del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

¿Seguro que tu problema está en la recepción del archivo SVG/XML?

Prueba con esto:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "resouces/mapa/mapa.svg",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(xml) {
        console.log(xml);
    }
});
```

Yo creo que el problema puede estar en el uso de la librería Raphael en la línea:

```
$("#div1").html(xml);
```

Debería revisar [esta librería](https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic) que te puede ayudar a convertir el SVG/XML en un SET de *raphael.js*.